# Implementing search in angular with angular.copy

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, filter

I have a simple button that when clicked, it will filter a list and return the filtered list:

```
var originalArray = [{name: "A", number: 1},{name: "B", number: 2},....]
```

And here is the `filter` function

```
function filterList(filterName, filterNumber) {
    var filteredList = angular.copy(originalArray);

    filteredList = filteredList.filter(function(item){
        return item.name === name
    }

    return filteredList
}
```

My question is am I using the right way to implement this feature? suppose that user clicks `search` button 10000 times ! do I have a 10000 copy of my `originalArray`?

Comment: You do not need to copy it at all. By using `filter` you will get a new array.

Comment: You don't need to use angular.copy on the original Array. .filter() will return a new one.

Comment: some one write its comment as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As filter returns just an array, use that instead and you won't need to use `angular.copy`

```
function filterList(filterName, filterNumber) {
    return originalArray.filter(function(item){
        return item.name === name
    }
}
```

That said there are better ways of doing this if you're doing this from a view. [Angular already has built in tools for filtering.](https://dzone.com/articles/angularjs-different-ways-using)

Answer (score 1):

As [str](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39120523/implementing-search-in-angular-with-angular-copy/39120718#comment65586836_39120523) commented - you don't need to copy the array, `filter` returns you a new array with only the appropriate items.

You should take a look at [ngFilter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) - there is an example there and it looks very much what you are looking for, effortless.